# \newline command like \xspace

Tags: errors, xspace

i wanted to ask if there is in any package a `\newline` command that works like `\xspace`, to avoid the "there is no line to end here." error.
In fact i have a

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\Teo}{gmm}{\textbf{Theprem\IfNoValueTF{#1}{}{ #1}:}\begin{addmargin}[0.8cm]{0cm}#2\\ \Dim{#3}\end{addmargin}}
```

And i got to end my hypothesis (second argument) with a

```
\begin{itemize}\end{itemize}
```

Comment: `gmm`? What's the idea behind this strange choice? Please, make a full (albeit minimal) example.

Comment: xspace isn't avoiding an error condition it's just adding space. there are very few use cases for using `\\ ` outside of tables, and certainly not in positions that give errors.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

The cited error arises when a `\newline` follows a `\par`.  Here I introduce `\mynewline`.

I originally suggested the `tabto` package, using a `\tabto{0pt}` to stand in for `\newline`.  This has a slightly different behavior, however, in that successive invocations of `\tabto{0pt}` will result in only a single `\newline`.

Andrew then reminded that the error originates because `\newline`does not operate in vertical mode.  Therefore, a suitable alternative declaration for `\mynewline` (requiring no packages) would simply be `\leavevmode\newline`.

Here I show both possibilities

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabto}
\newcommand\mynewline{\leavevmode\newline}
\begin{document}
a

b\mynewline
c

d\mynewline

e

\mynewline
f
\mynewline
\mynewline
\mynewline
\mynewline
g

\renewcommand\mynewline{\tabto{0pt}}
\mynewline
f
\mynewline
\mynewline
\mynewline
\mynewline
g
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Simpler is `\leavevmode\newline`.

Comment: @AndrewSwann Go rain on my parade, why don't you!  Would you be offended if I take your advice to update?

Comment: Don't fret Steven, I wanted something like \tabto a couple of weeks ago, but did not know of that package.  Now I know.

Comment: @dedded Don't forget, with the `tabto` package, the extremely useful parameter `\TabPrevPos`, for restoring the tab to the most recent prior position.